# Unable to instantiate activity component

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, manifest

I have a MainActivity.java file in my package but when I run my application the log cat says:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity Component: Didn't find class com.example.csmcatering.MainActivity on path...

I have this Manifest File:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.csmcatering.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure your MainActivity.java is in that package?

Comment: Yes I'm sure @JorgeAlfaro

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. 
My MainActivity extends FragmentActivity that is in android.support.v4...
I imported that jar in the right way in my project but I didn't checked it under "java Build Path / Order and export".